# Big query REGEXP_REPLACE text to integer

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

How to extract integer value from the following format text
For example, this text ($99.99) should return -99.
and 99.99 should return 99
and 80 should return 80

I tried use `[REGEXP_REPLACE][1](text, r'[^\d]+',"")`
but I'm not fimiliar with regex, I red this [documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt) but not understand how to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
cast(regexp_replace(translate(text, '($)', '-'), r'\.\d*', '') as int64) int
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(text, r'\(\$(\d+)\.\d+\)', r'-\1'), r'\.\d+$', '') as int64) int
```

See [regex #1 proof](https://regex101.com/r/miX43f/2/) and [regex proof #2](https://regex101.com/r/miX43f/3).

**`\(\$(\d+)\.\d+\)` explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```

**`\.\d+$` explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Btw, note - this is for BigQuery - so `'-$1'` should be `r'-\1'`

Comment: not sure why this was upvoted and even twice - it just does not work!! try for example `$99.99` and `(99.99)`